# Convert ordered elements containing only level IDs into parent/child structure

Tags: javascript

Let's say that I have an array of ordered objects like:

```
var arr = [
   {levelId: 0, name: 'A'},
   {levelId: 1, name: 'B'},
   {levelId: 2, name: 'C'},
   {levelId: 2, name: 'D'},
   {levelId: 3, name: 'E'},
   {levelId: 1, name: 'F'},
   {levelId: 0, name: 'G'},
   {levelId: 1, name: 'H'}
];
```

so that the order they have in the array matters for their structure, so that

```
A -> B -> C
A -> B -> D -> E
A -> F
G -> H
```

Is there a good way to convert this into a good structure with parent child relationships? Googled for 2 hours, but haven't come up with anything good.

Here is an example

```js
const newArr = [{
    levelId: 0,
    name: 'A',
    children: [{
        levelId: 1,
        name: 'B',
        children: [{
            levelId: 2,
            name: 'C',
            children: []
          },
          {
            levelId: 2,
            name: 'D',
            children: [{
              levelId: 3,
              name: 'E'
            }]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        levelId: 1,
        name: 'F',
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    levelId: 0,
    name: 'G',
    children: [{
      levelId: 1,
      name: 'H',
      children: []
    }]
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you want to approach?

Comment: Start by explaining/finding what you want your structure to be at the end. THEN tackle the problem of converting your input into that structure.So here, are you looking for advice on the end structure, or how to convert?

Comment: Sorry for being vague! No I know how i want the end structure to be. Something like this: https://pastebin.com/pjjp2apB (too long to post). It's for later use with Angular in an ngFor-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array for the levels and an object for the result for the nested object, which reflects the given data.

```js
var array = [{ levelId: 0, name: 'A' }, { levelId: 1, name: 'B' }, { levelId: 2, name: 'C' }, { levelId: 2, name: 'D' }, { levelId: 3, name: 'E' }, { levelId: 1, name: 'F' }, { levelId: 0, name: 'G' }, { levelId: 1, name: 'H' }],
    result = {},
    levels = [result];

array.forEach(({ levelId, name }) =>
    levels[levelId][name] = levels[levelId][name] || (levels[levelId + 1] = {})
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

To get objects with children, you could change the result to an array and use an object for pushing.

```js
var array = [{ levelId: 0, name: 'A' }, { levelId: 1, name: 'B' }, { levelId: 2, name: 'C' }, { levelId: 2, name: 'D' }, { levelId: 3, name: 'E' }, { levelId: 1, name: 'F' }, { levelId: 0, name: 'G' }, { levelId: 1, name: 'H' }],
    result = [],
    levels = [result];

array.forEach(({ levelId, name }) =>
    levels[levelId].push({ levelId, name, children: levels[levelId + 1] = [] })
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! (and so much shorter than what I was trying to come up with :) ) 

Too low reputation to upvote officially, but says it was recorded anyway.

Comment: Actually now that I started working on it, I need it to be an array with objects that - if they have children - adds an array with children cotaining  objects and so on.. (like in the example written on my edited question). I'm trying to change your code so that it works like that, but I don't quite understand the part with:
levels[levelId][name] = levels[levelId][name] || (levels[levelId + 1] = {})

Could you explain it? :)